# Why does PHP Contribution API not filter on contact_id in 4.6.2?

Tags: wordpress, api, contributions, php, 4.6.2

We recentely upgrade from 4.5.x to 4.6.2 and after that the following API call from PHP does not filter on contact_id and return all contributions for all contacts.

```
$params = array(
    'contact_id' => $contact_id,
);
$api->Contribution->Get($params);
```

In the backend explorer, the follow error occurs:

```
{
    "is_error": 1,
    "error_message": "A fatal error was triggered: CiviCRM is not of the type Int"
}
```

Good ideas very welcome :)

Comment: I just tested and can confirm that this is a bug.  Please submit a bug on issues.civicrm.org, reference this StackExchange question, and please note that it's a regression, so it will get more attention.

Comment: Please consider answering your own question, stating the issue is a confirmed bug. It would be great if you also include a direct link to the bug report in your answer, to help future users who have this same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug and has been reported by @huulbaek as https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16393?jql=project%20%3D%20CRM